# How to install 2 Anacondas (Python 2.7 and 3.5) on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I want to use Python 2 and 3 versions. I've read about the use of  `conda` environments, but it seems inconvenient to write constantly  to the terminal `source (de)activate py27`. How can I choose the kernel version using the command, as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOs56.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in that image is Jupyter Notebook. You  need to create an environment with Jupyter and the python version you want:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 jupyter ipykernel
```

Acttivate the environment:

```
source activate py27
```

Run the following command:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Deactivate:

```
source deactivate
```

The kernel is now available when you launch Jupyter Notebook. You can verify both Python2 and Python3 kernels exist with the following command:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```